# Push перезаписывает значения (объекты) в массиве, а не добавляет новые

Tags: массивы, reactjs, объекты, localstorage, push

У меня есть 2 `useEffect` и 2 массива, когда я нажимаю на кнопку туда должно пушится значение, и автоматически сохранять в локал сторедж, когда я кликаю, добавляется объект в массив, но при повторном клике уже на другого пользователя появляется новый объект, который перезаписывает предыдущий объект в массиве и в `localStorage`. Подскажите, что делать и как это исправить

```js
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
const [likedId, setLikedId] = useState("");

const liked = []
const disliked = []

useEffect(() => {
  const newArr = users.filter((item) => item.id !== likedId);
  const getLikedUser = users.filter((item) => item.id === likedId);

  if (getLikedUser.length !== 0) {
    liked.push(...getLikedUser);
    localStorage.setItem("liked", JSON.stringify(liked));
    console.log(liked);
  }

  setUsers(newArr);
}, [likedId]);
```

html:

```html
<div
    className="main__menu-item menu__cross"
    onClick={() => setLikedId(users[users.length - 1].id)}
>
  <img src={cross} alt="dislike" />
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если Вам нужно добавлять информацию, то сначала нужно считать старую информацию из локалсторэдж getItem(), и уже к ней добавлять новую инфу.

Comment: Положить ваши массивы в переменную состояния и пушить данные туда. В текущем виде, каждый вызов компонента создает новый пустой массив, далее вы туда пушите данные и сохраняете...